# PHP and APC, File Upload Progress not Cacheing?

Tags: php, file-upload, apc

I've been all over the internet reading up on APC, and it seems like a nifty way to detect file Uploading.

I am, however, having a problem.

I know how to call files and everything using Ajax, and that is what I am planning to do, but for Testing sake, I'm doing something like this.

Ok, so I have 3 files.

form.php
upload.php
status.php

form.php contains:

```
<input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" value="1234" />
<input type="file" id="fileIn" name="file" />
```

(I am aware that I will need to use a unique ID in APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS. Again, this is just for testings sake.)

Ok, Now Upload.php has the regular PHP upload script:

```
$origin = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file(...etc...etc)...
```

And Status.php uses APC:

```
$upload = apc_fetch('upload_1234');
if ($upload) {
    if ($upload['done'])
        $percent = 100;
    else if ($upload['total'] == 0)
        $percent = 0;
    else
        $percent = $upload['current'] / $upload['total'] * 100;

echo $percent;
}
```

Now What I am doing is uploading a file using a regular HTTP method, and using another window to monitor Status.php.

The problem is; Status.php returns nothing!

However, If i write
    print_r(apc_fetch('upload_1234'));

into upload.php, it returns the correct array, with all the details etc..

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: also, apc.rfc1867 and such are all enabled and turned on.

Comment: There's apparently an alternate option available: http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress

Comment: Found one, it works really well!

Answer (score 2):

When this happens, something to check is that your hidden input element with the APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS key is placed **immediately** before the file input in your form.

I know the form in the example above does do this, but it's easily missed in a more complicated form layout.

Comment: Shame this answer didn't get accepted. I wasn't aware the hidden input had to come before the file input.